# 500 Error when trying to login or register

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jwt, bcrypt

I've been trying to fix my code so that i can sign in or register a user. I am using MongoDB as a database and I had no trouble when registering, but after adding to check if the jwst token is in storage im getting the error.

My backend called server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const routesUrls = require("./routes/routes");
const cors = require("cors");

dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_ACCESS);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use("/api", routesUrls);

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Server is running on port 4000"));
```

The backend api

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require("./auth");
const UserModel = require("../models/UserModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

router.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { fullName, email, password } = req.body;

    // check if the user already exists
    const userExists = await UserModel.findOne({ email });
    if (userExists) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "User already exists" });
    }

    // hash the password before saving to the database
    const saltPassword = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const securePassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltPassword);

    // create a new user object
    const signedUpUser = new UserModel({
      fullName: req.body.fullName,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: securePassword,
    });

    // save the user to the database
    await signedUpUser.save();

    // Create JWT payload
    const payload = {
      user: {
        id: signedUpUser.id,
        email: signedUpUser.email,
      },
    };

    // Generate JWT and return to client
    jwt.sign(
      payload,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: "1h" },
      (err, token) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        // Store the token in browser's local storage
        localStorage.setItem("token", token);
        res.status(201).json({ message: "User created successfully", token });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server Error" });
  }
});

router.post("/signin", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    // find the user by email
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid email or password" });
    }

    // check if the password is correct
    const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!passwordMatch) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid email or password" });
    }

    // Create JWT payload
    const payload = {
      user: {
        id: user.id,
        email: user.email,
      },
    };

    // Generate JWT and return to client
    jwt.sign(
      payload,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      { expiresIn: "1h" },
      (err, token) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        // Store the token in browser's local storage
        localStorage.setItem("token", token);
        res.json({ message: "Sign in successful", token });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server Error" });
  }
});

router.get("/user", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.user.id;
    const user = await UserModel.findById(userId);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
    }
    res.json({ fullName: user.fullName, email: user.email });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server Error" });
  }
});

router.get("/signin", async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Signin Page" });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The auth being used in that code

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("config");

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  // Get token from header
  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");

  // Check if token exists
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: "No token, authorization denied" });
  }

  // Verify token
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtSecret"));
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: "Token is not valid" });
  }
};
```

The sign in front end on port 3000

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Login = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const handleEmailChange = (event) => {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
    setPassword(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const credentials = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:4000/api/signin", credentials)
      .then((response) => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        props.history.push("/");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    console.log("Token in local storage:", token);
    if (token) {
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = undefined;
    props.history.push("/login");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="form-div">
          {isAuthenticated ? (
            <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
          ) : (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email"
                onChange={handleEmailChange}
                value={email}
                className="form-control form-group"
              />

              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={handlePasswordChange}
                value={password}
                className="form-control form-group"
              />
              <input
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-danger btn-block"
                value="Login"
              />
            </form>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

The sign up or register

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Register extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      fullName: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
    this.changeFullName = this.changeFullName.bind(this);
    this.changeEmail = this.changeEmail.bind(this);
    this.changePassword = this.changePassword.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  changeFullName(event) {
    this.setState({
      fullName: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  changeEmail(event) {
    this.setState({
      email: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  changePassword(event) {
    this.setState({
      password: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const registered = {
      fullName: this.state.fullName,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    };
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:4000/api/signup", registered)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token); // Store the token in localStorage
        window.location = "/"; // Redirect to homepage
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="form-div">
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Full Name"
                onChange={this.changeFullName}
                value={this.state.fullName}
                className="form-control form-group"
              />

              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email"
                onChange={this.changeEmail}
                value={this.state.email}
                className="form-control form-group"
              />

              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={this.changePassword}
                value={this.state.password}
                className="form-control form-group"
              />
              <input
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-danger btn-block"
                value="Register"
              />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Register;
```

The error is this [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDp8f.jpg]

Comment: Check the logs of your server to find out what the 500 error actually is

Comment: I already check but im getting Cannot GET /api/signup

Comment: @GabrielGranell No, not in the browser, he meant check your `console.error(err.message);` on the backend side what does it prints? This is a server error, so is the server even started? Also using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) on the backend is redundant, so remove that